# How to get a surrounding text for a found string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

This is a noob question

Suppose I search a string `S` for a pattern `P`. Now I would like to display a substring of the string, which surrounds `P`. The substring should be only one line (i.e. `N` characters) and contain *whole* words. How would you code it in `JavaScript`?

For example:
Let `S` = "Hello world, welcome to the universe", `P` = "welcome", and `N` = 15. The naive solution gives "ld, welcome to " (adding 4 chars before and after `P`). I would like to "round" it up to "world, welcome to".

Can regular expressions help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the regular expression you wanted:

```
/\s?([^\s]+\swelcome\s[^\s]+)\s?/i    //very simple, no a strange bunch of [] and {}
```

***Explanation:***

What you are trying to match is actually

> " world, welcome to "

without the spaces before and after, therefore:

```
\s?       //the first space (if found)
(         //define the string position you want
[^\s]+    //any text (first word before "welcome", no space)
\s        //a space
welcome   //you word
\s        //a space
[^\s]+    //the next world (no space inside)
)         //that's it, I don't want the last space
\s?       //the space at the end (if found)
```

***Applying:***

```
function find_it(p){
    var s = "Hello world, welcome to the universe",
        reg = new RegExp("\\s?([^\\s]+\\s" + p + "\\s[^\\s]+)\\s?", "i");

    return s.match(reg) && s.match(reg)[1];
}

find_it("welcome");   //"world, welcome to"

find_it("world,");    //"Hello world, welcome"

find_it("universe");  //null (because there is no word after "universe")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is, what your are looking for.

```
$a = ($n - length of $p)/2
/[a-zA-Z0-9]{$a}$p[a-zA-Z0-9]{$a}/
```

I used dollars to show where the variables are. You didn't provide enough code to write a concrete example.

Comment: What is this? Why `($n - length of $p)/2`?

Comment: because $n is the total length minus the length of the searched string divided with 2 because he wanted the same length before and after.

Comment: Um... he didn't say that. He said `I would like to "round" it up`

Comment: Okay, I understand it this way. :-)

Comment: @Oliver You are correct. The surrounding text should be approximately N chars with the pattern in the middle.